# Is there any way to automate some actions in Visual Studio 2015 when a solution first opened?

Tags: visual-studio

**Context**

A fellow developer clones (or simply downloads and unzips) and **opens** a VS 2015 solution in her/his developer machine. I would like to automate some tasks to be happen ***within VS 2015 IDE*** this time.

**Question**

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: I sure hope not. Do you want the good old times back, where opening a Word document launched macros that destroyed your PC?

Comment: When you build a VS project it probably loads executables and PowerShelll scrips from internet (NuGet) and runs them. What's the difference. Also please note I am talking VS IDE actions, saying:  "within VS 2015 IDE", like opening a readme in VS IDE editor